# How to display this data from console.log(element.faculty_name) to template in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

> I have the function of display data from major table on MySQL. I want to display the type of that major by comparing with the id of the faculty table like below. I have it displayed on console.log, how do I display it on the template?

**Template tag**

```
<td>
    {{ filterFaculty }}
</td>
```

**Script tag**

```
data() {
    return {
        majors:[],
        faculties:[],
        form: new Form({
            major_id:'',
            major_code:'',
            major_name:'',
            major_faculty:'',
            major_status: '',
        }),
    };
},
computed: {
    filterFaculty() {
        for(let i in this.majors) {
            this.faculties.forEach((element) => {
                if(element.faculty_code==this.majors[i].major_faculty) {
                    console.log(element.faculty_name);
                }else {
                    return '-';
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchFaculties();
    this.fetchMajors();
},
methods: {
  fetchFaculties(page_url) {
        let vm = this;
        page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-faculty/faculty/faculty';
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.faculties = res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    fetchMajors(page_url) {
        let vm = this;
        page_url = '../../api/admin/edu-major/major/'+this.currentEntries+'?page='+this.pagination.current_page;
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.majors = res.data;
            this.pagination = res.meta;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve that, I think the easiest is to do following:

Define something in your data - like `inputText` and than set your `element.faculty_name` to this - like following:

```
data() {
  return {
    inputText: "",
  }
}

computed: {
    filterFaculty() {
        for(let i in this.majors) {
            this.faculties.forEach((element) => {
                if(element.faculty_code==this.majors[i].major_faculty) {
                    this.inputText = element.faculty_name; //Changed here
                }else {
                    return '-';
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

and than reference it in your template like this:

```
<td>
    {{ inputText }}
</td>
```

This should solve your problem!

Comment: thank you for help me. But tell me how to operate on a table list